# sqltransaction insert a double record while insert data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sqltransaction

I am using that sqltransaction for the insert multiple tables each data.

But I have problem that have the database have the two same data.

What should I do for solve that problem?

please help me? Thanx

```
SqlConnection baglanti = system.baglan();

            SqlCommand Trislem1_Ekle = new SqlCommand("Insert tblTr (Ad,TipID,BolgeID,Yerler,Resim) values(@Ad,@TipID,@BolgeID,@Yerler,@Resim)  SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", baglanti);
            SqlCommand Tr2_TrAciklama = new SqlCommand("Insert tblTrAciklamaDetay (TrID,TrProgram) values((SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('tblTr')),@TrProgram)", baglanti);

            Trislem1_Ekle.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ad", txtTrAd.Text);
            Trislem1_Ekle.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TipID", dlTrTip.SelectedValue);

            Trislem1_Ekle.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BolgeID", BolgeID.SelectedValue);
            Trislem1_Ekle.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Yerler", Yerler.Text);
            Trislem1_Ekle.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Resim", Resim.SelectedValue);

            Tr2_TrAciklama.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TrProgram", TrProgram.Text);

            SqlTransaction sqlTrans = baglanti.BeginTransaction();

            Trislem1_Ekle.Transaction = sqlTrans;
            Tr2_TrAciklama.Transaction = sqlTrans;
            try
            {
                Trislem1_Ekle.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Tr2_TrAciklama.ExecuteNonQuery();
                string SonIDGelen = Trislem1_Ekle.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
               sqlTrans.Commit();

            }
           catch (Exception hata)
            {
                Response.Write("İşleminiz yapılamadı, Oluşan Hatanın Detayı<br />" + hata);
               sqlTrans.Rollback(); 
            }

            finally
            {  
                baglanti.Close();
                baglanti.Dispose();
                Trislem1_Ekle.Dispose();
                Tr2_TrAciklama.Dispose();

            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I see, you executing your `Trislem1_Ekle` command twice.

One with

```
Trislem1_Ekle.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

and the other one with;

```
string SonIDGelen = Trislem1_Ekle.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Deleting the first one seems enough. Both `ExecuteNonQuery` and `ExecuteScalar` executes your query, and `ExecuteScalar` returns first column of the first row additionally.

Instead of disposing your database connections and commands manually, use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) instead.

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conString))
{    
   using(SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
   {
      // Create your commands
      // Add your parameter values
      // Execute your commands
   }
}
```

And don't use `AddWithValue` method. It may generate some unexptected results. Use `.Add()` method and overloads instead.

- [Can we stop using `AddWithValue()` already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Answer (score 0):

try like this

I think you are executing `ExecuteScalar()` twice on Command `Trislem1_Ekle`

```
            Trislem1_Ekle.ExecuteNonQuery();    
            Tr2_TrAciklama.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string SonIDGelen = Trislem1_Ekle.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

Replace with this:

```
            string SonIDGelen = Trislem1_Ekle.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
            Tr2_TrAciklama.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Not nice to give an incorrect answer and then fix it when you see the correct one. Better delete and try another one. They comes every second

Comment: @Steve see my first edit...formatting & adding Expl req. time or You can see my answers time 19:07:25Z